# C# out variable in list

Tags: c#, out

i m studying the book Exam Ref 70-483:Programming in C#.

in the chapter Using concurrent collection, there is an example:

```
   #region Listing 1-30
        ConcurrentBag<int> bag = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
        bag.Add(42);
        bag.Add(21);
        int result;
        if (bag.TryTake(out result))
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        if (bag.TryPeek(out result))
            Console.WriteLine("There is a next item: {0}", result);
        #endregion
```

the question is : how it connect the variable int result with bag ?

there is no decalaration result = bag.DoSomeThingInLinq.

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you understand how `out` variables work? And you also understand that `TryTake()` is (potentially) returning *two* values - the value taken, plus a result flag?

Comment: bag.TryTake(out result)

Since"result" is already declared. "out result" connects it.
I think, you should read about how "out" works.

The out keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference. It makes the formal parameter an alias for the argument, which must be a variable. In other words, any operation on the parameter is made on the argument. It is like the ref keyword, except that ref requires that the variable be initialized before it is passed.

MSDN link about "out":
<https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how it connect the variable int result with bag ?

```
bag.TryTake(out result)
```

The line above attempts to remove and return an item from the bag. If successful (i.e. when it returns true) then the out parameter `result` will contain the value taken.

When a method uses an out parameter, this means that it will be passed by reference. The method using it then has to assign a value to it.

See:

[ConcurrentBag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1.trytake?view=netframework-4.8)

[out parameter modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier)